# At what rate can firestore create new documents in a collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading records from a CSV to firestore using Java on AppEngine. Here is my code:

```
Map<String,Object> record = new HashMap<>();
record.put("value", value);
record.put("position", position);
record.put("status", "pending");
records.document().create(record);
```

where records is a reference to a collection. I can upload files up to around 50K records without problem. But beyond this point I start loosing records, ie. documents are not created, silently.

Notice that I dont wait for the ApiFuture for performance reasons. Do I really have to wait for it and retry if not successful?

Isn't firestore supposed to scale well and handle high volume of document creation without problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that writes to databases should **always** check for errors.  This involves using the ApiFuture or whatever mechanism is provided by the SDK for the language you're using.

There are, in fact, write rate limits in Firestore.  Please consult the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions).  Currently, the max writes per second for an entire database is 10,000.

Comment: My write rate is way bellow 1000/second, the limit for collection writes.
The official docs repeatedly states that waiting for response is optional, like "block on response if required" or "(optional) block on operation"
Plus, time for upload will be huge if I wait for every create to finish!
Any thoughts?
Thank you

Comment: Sure, waiting is optional, but if you want to find out if something went wrong and what the error was, you need to use the ApiFuture.